# Sum Foreignkey objects to loop

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying create a table with 2 columns: 
1) Collections and 2) Qualified Sales.

Like the image above.
[image]

Each `book` count the own `qualified_sales`.

The `Qualified sales`(column in the table) must sum all `qualified_sales` of all `books` of each `collection`.

models.py

```
class Publishing_company(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Collection(models.Model):
     publishing_company = models.ForeignKey(Publishing_company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Book(models.Model):
     publishing_company = models.ForeignKey(Publishing_company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Sale(models.Model):
     book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     qualified_sale = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py

```
def qlf_sales(request):
    book = Collection.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    qualified_sum = Sale.objects.filter(user=request.user, book__publishing_company__collection__in=book).aggregate(Sum('qualified_sale'))['qualified_sale__sum'] or 0

    context = {'qualified_sum': qualified_sum}

    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

template.html

```
{% for collection in collections %}
  <tr>
     <td>{{collection}}</td>
     <td>{{qualified_sum}}%</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

But this code not work. Dont appear any debug error, but in the all fields in the Qualified Sales' column appear the same value: the sum of all `qualified_sales` of all `sales` of all `book`.

why didn't separate by collection?

If anyone can help me. Please i go a lot grateful.

Comment: You are not passing `collections` context variable to the template.

Comment: Sorry, but how can I do that?

Comment: Now appear the same value in the all Qualifield_sale field: the sum of all ```qualified_sales``` of all ```sales``` of all ```book```